# "Insert AssignmentOperator expression" error JAVA

Tags: java

I keep getting the error "Insert AssignmentOperator expression to complete expression" My program is to basically choose a random location that an animal is in. I am writing the arrary and variables right also, right???

The problem occurs in the if statement; the specific code is giraffeLocation [r.nextInt(giraffeLocation.length)];

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class animaltracker {
    public static void main(String[] args){
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            Random r = new Random();

            char giraffe;
            char rhino;
            char hipopotamus;

            String[] giraffeLocation;
            giraffeLocation = new String[3];
            giraffeLocation[0] = ("Africa");
            giraffeLocation[1] = ("Russia");
            giraffeLocation[2] = ("Germany");





            System.out.println("Welcome to the animal tracker!");
            try { Thread.currentThread().sleep(800); }
            catch ( Exception e ) { }

            System.out.println("Which animal shall we be tracking today?");
            try { Thread.currentThread().sleep(800); }
            catch (Exception e) { }

            System.out.println("\nGiraffe?\nRhino?\nHipopotamus?");
            String animal = s.nextLine();
                if(animal.equalsIgnoreCase("giraffe")){
                     **giraffeLocation [r.nextInt(giraffeLocation.length)];**

                    System.out.println("Your giraffe is in, " + giraffeLocation );
                }







        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you've forgotten to actually _do_ something with the value at that index in the array

Comment: _giraffeLocation [r.nextInt(giraffeLocation.length)]_ what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: @PradeepSimha i am trying to print out a random location from the giraffeLocation array to the console. but a different location each time.

Comment: @user2548682, below answer holds good. You are not storing it to any variable, so you are getting above error.

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually storing the look-up of the random location anywhere, you want something like this:

```
String tmp = giraffeLocation [r.nextInt(giraffeLocation.length)];

System.out.println("Your giraffe is in, " + tmp );
```

Answer (score 1):

fixed code should be something like this..

```
   public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random r = new Random();

        String[] giraffeLocation;
        giraffeLocation = new String[3];
        giraffeLocation[0] = ("Africa");
        giraffeLocation[1] = ("Russia");
        giraffeLocation[2] = ("Germany");

        System.out.println("Welcome to the animal tracker!");
        try { Thread.currentThread().sleep(800); }
        catch ( Exception e ) { }

        System.out.println("Which animal shall we be tracking today?");
        try { Thread.currentThread().sleep(800); }
        catch (Exception e) { }

        System.out.println("\nGiraffe?\nRhino?\nHipopotamus?");
        String animal = s.nextLine();
            if(animal.equalsIgnoreCase("giraffe")){
                String location = "";
                try {
                     location = giraffeLocation [r.nextInt(giraffeLocation.length)];
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("EXCEPTIION");
                }                  
                System.out.println("Your giraffe is in, " + location );
            }
    }
```